# Assign image to different buttons

Tags: javascript, css

How can I make the picture change with each different button clicked and make the picture shown to be the default?

From the code snippet, please notice how each button should change the image.

Thank you!

```css
  * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.imagebox {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.imagebox img {
  position: relative;
  top: 40%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.textbox-cont {
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.textbox {
  color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  top: 53%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .imagebox,
  .textbox-cont {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
```

```html
<div class="imagebox"></div>
<img src="https://s.ftcdn.net/v2013/pics/all/curated/RKyaEDwp8J7JKeZWQPuOVWvkUjGQfpCx_cover_580.jpg?r=1a0fc22192d0c808b8bb2b9bcfbf4a45b1793687" alt="">
<div class="textbox-cont">
  <div class="textbox">
    Pick a color to see how it will look<br>
    <button style="margin: 8px;">Cobalt Blue</button><br>
    <button style="margin: 8px">Cobaltt Blue</button><br>
    <button style="margin: 8px">Cardinal Red</button><br>
    <button style="margin: 8px">Coral Orange</button><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to each button and change the image `src` attribute depending on the button `id`:

```js
const img = document.getElementById('img');
for (let button of document.getElementsByTagName('button')) {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    switch (button.id) {
      case 'but1': 
        img.src = "https://s.ftcdn.net/v2013/pics/all/curated/RKyaEDwp8J7JKeZWQPuOVWvkUjGQfpCx_cover_580.jpg?r=1a0fc22192d0c808b8bb2b9bcfbf4a45b1793687";
        break;
      case 'but2': 
        img.src = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTgfERcK1BcdgSekipirrCw6zpQJ9l40h48Musvp7-dfy8Ym3Yl&usqp=CAU";
        break;
      case 'but3': 
        img.src = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcS9wvzviWw6ag6p_aZgw6kRs267_3jpiI_gGCxvLh7U9QIVAmQa&usqp=CAU";
        break;
      case 'but4': 
        img.src = "https://xzdl43v0mdf2m45tz2aj7kkv35-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/orange-780x400.jpg";
        break;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.imagebox {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height:300px;
  position:relative;
}

.imagebox img{
  position:relative;
  top:40%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  overflow:hidden;
  width: 100%;
  
  
}

.textbox-cont {
  width: 50%;
  height:300px;
  float: right;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.textbox{
  color: #000000;
  position:absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
  padding:20px;
   top:53%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  
  
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .imagebox,
  .textbox-cont {
    width: 100%;
   display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
```

```html
<div class="imagebox">
  <img id="img" src="https://s.ftcdn.net/v2013/pics/all/curated/RKyaEDwp8J7JKeZWQPuOVWvkUjGQfpCx_cover_580.jpg?r=1a0fc22192d0c808b8bb2b9bcfbf4a45b1793687" 
  alt="">
</div>
<div class="textbox-cont">
  <div class="textbox">
    Pick a color to see how it will look<br> 
    <button style="margin: 8px" id="but1">Cobalt Blue</button><br>
    <button style="margin: 8px" id="but2">Cobaltt Blue</button><br>
    <button style="margin: 8px" id="but3">Cardinal Red</button><br>
    <button style="margin: 8px" id="but4">Coral Orange</button><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm. How can i add width and height to each picture, seems some of them show bigger. Thank you very much for the time spent!